# mongoose .save creates document at different collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, save

I´m finding out that after saving a document into a collection correctly, mongoose is creating a document at a different collection i´m not referencing at any moment.

```
   let groupSchema = new Group(

            {
              role: "EDA_USER_ROLE",
              group_name: "",
              name: "SDA_BASIC",
              users: []
            }
          )
        
          groupSchema.save()
```

Group schema is defined in a different file, and it actually saves this document correctly.
But, magiclly, this creates an empty document at a different collection called `data-source`, with only the `_id` and `_v` fields:

[document wrongly created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrmkZ.png)

If there´s anybody that could help me, i´ll be very greatful. I haven´t found any crossed figure or code line where this could happend.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Models with your Schema as per the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)? Please post the code where you define your schema, where the model is created, the route that triggers the creation of this new document and your database connection. There could be a number of reasons this is happening.

Comment: @jQueeny thanks for your feedback. It was actually a mistake along the code that misleaded the creation. Thanks for interest. This issue is done.